# How to create a relative path using System.Uri

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to create a URI like this

```
Uri uri = new Uri("file:///Pages/Menu/Page.xaml");
```

So I have a WPF project and its path is like this: `C:/Programing/MyProjectName/`
Now the path to my file are `C:/Programing/MyProjectName/Pages/Menu/Page.xaml`
as you saw above the path I give to the Uri is `file:///Pages/Menu/Page.xaml` when I run this I get the error can't find the part of the path `C:/Pages/Menu/Page.xaml` which I expect because as I said above my files path is `C:/Programing/MyProjectName/Pages/Menu/Page.xaml`
so my question is, is there any way to use a relative path in my Uri, I want to use a relative path because my app will not always be in the same folder.

Incase your wondering why I'm using a Uri is because I'm setting the Source property on a WPF frame and it uses Uri instead of string.

Comment: Why are you using a URI instead of just a path (using `System.Path`)

Comment: The code snippet you posted is perfectly valid. Creating a URI does not validate the existence of the URI. Post your full code.

Comment: Because I'm setting the Source property on a WPF frame and it uses Uri instead of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to load a Page, use a [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#resource-file-pack-uris):

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pages/Menu/Page.xaml");
```

Which could also be written like this:

```
var uri = new Uri("/Pages/Menu/Page.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```